# making wysiwyg text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, wysiwyg, text-editor

I'd like to make my own text editor. I'm trying to follow the example of several other well established editors and use a hidden `<textarea>` and visible `<iframe>` combo.

I'm having trouble with the very first step of keying up the `<iframe>`. I can get execCommand to work on a *contenteditable* `<div>` to, e.g., make text **BOLD** but having trouble doing the same on the `<iframe>`.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-bold">bold</button>
<textarea id="input" name="input" style="display: none;">Start typing..</textarea>
<iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:true;" style="">  </iframe>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
    $(function() {
        var currentBtn;
        $("#input").focus(function() {
            currentBtn = this;
        });
        $(".btn").on( 'click', '.btn-bold', function(){
            var $this=$(this);
            if($this.hasClass("btn-bold")){ document.execCommand('bold', false, null);}
            $(currentBtn).contents().focus();
        });
    });
```

I know I need to perform the execCommand on the iframe document and not the parent document but just not sure how to do this. Currently, this code doesn't allow me to keyup the iframe so can't test the effect of the bold button.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're creating really a text editor (not a rich-text editor), the best solution to do it is use `<PRE>` (in actual page without `IFRAME`) as a text pad. With this element you can use real tabs too.

Comment: hi Teemu, i'd like to create a rich-text editor but thanks for the input, do you have any suggestions on how to keyup the `iframe`?

Comment: Well, just like Derek says in the last comment, load a page in `IFRAME`, so you'll really have something to refer to. Then you've to learn a lot about selecting, TextRange-object and selection events etc. offered by jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) and wrap `<b>` around the selection to bold. You can perform other tasks with this method too.

Demo: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn-history/r511/trunk/demos/core.html

### Edit

How to make `iframe` editable:

```
window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].contentEditable = true;​
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vpCXN/
- http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vpCXN/10/ - with bold button

Comment: hi Derek, i'd rather learn first principles, but thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any suggestions on how to keyup the iframe?

Comment: @tim peterson, Wrapping elements is very simple and basic. But if you want to know how to keyup in frame, here's how: Set an event listener inside the `iframe`, then do whatever you want there. (I don't really understand what you mean by `keyup`.)

Comment: i mean i'd like the iframe to be `contenteditable` so that when i click on it I can actually type.

Comment: You can create a `conteneditable` `<body>` inside the `<iframe>`.

Comment: hi Derek, thanks for the demo, that's great! I just realized that iOS Safari doesn't support `contenteditable` so i need a workaround to allow people to still input text and format it (make bold, etc.) on mobile devices. I tested the wysiwyg rich-text editor, Cleditor: http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/ using my iPhone and I can input text in their demo editor box. I guess to mimic this I just need to toggle the visibility of the `textarea` and `iframe` depending on the useragent?

Comment: Also, i've updated your jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vpCXN/8/ I'm trying to get the bold button to work on the text but I think the `window.frames[0].document` part of the code is not referencing the right `iframe`. It's an iframe within an iframe and `frames[1]` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You entered `$this` instead of `$(this)`. That's why it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vpCXN/10/

Answer (score 0):

This might help.But it in in javascript and I am running it in google chrome.Here is the code:

```
<div>
  <input type="button" onClick="bo()" value="B"> 
  <input type="button" onClick="under()" value="U">
  <input type='button' onClick="f_size()" value="f_size">

<br>
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe><br> 
<input type="button" onClick="asd()" value="get_innerhtml"><br> 
<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';


function bo(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('bold',false,null); 
}
function under(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('underline',false,null);
}
function f_size(){
    var size = prompt('Enter a size 1 - 7', '');
    richTextField.document.execCommand('FontSize',false,size);
}
function asd(){

var text=document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
document.getElementById('myTextArea').value=text;
}
</script>
```